# SQL Inner Join on IN statement

Tags: sql, left-join

i'm trying to get vehicle data from `vehicles`, however I need to display the vehicle make even if it does not exist within `vehicles` if the make ID is within a certain range.

**vehicles**

```
group: 1996
make: 8

group: 1996
make: 6

group: 1996
make: 3
```

**make**

```
id: 01
code: 8
description: Audi

id: 02
code: 6
description: BMW

id: 03
code: 2
description: Mercedes
```

Current query:

```
SELECT v.make, vm.description
FROM vehicles v 
LEFT JOIN makes vm ON vm.code IN (6,8)
WHERE v.group = 1996 AND v.make IN (8,6)
GROUP BY make
```

My results currently:

```
make: 8
description: Audi
```

Expected results:

```
make: 8
description: Audi

make: 6
description: BMW
```

Comment: what is common field for both tables ?

Comment: You have no JOIN condition! Perhaps v.make = vm.code?

Comment: Why v.group = 404 where in your data set is 1996?

Comment: Does id 8 and 6 belongs to  v.group = 404?

Comment: You need improve your sample data. And explain the logic for the border cases.

Comment: Hi. Your code is a (filtered) cross product: it returns all combinations of a row from each table. You could have used cross join or inner join or right join. From your output example, which unfortunately is not accompanied by a specification of what it is an example of, you likely want a left join of rows where v.make=vm.code. But you don't clearly say what you want. "get vehicle data from vehicles" doesn't mention the role of make or join. Why do you group by? If it's just for distinct rows, use select distinct. Show your key DDL. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Where clause after Left join could potentially take it as `inner join`, I think if i understood u correctly. You wont need a group by either. Remove`where` clause. Predicate on `where` moves to `inner join`

```
SELECT v.make, vm.description
FROM vehicles v 
LEFT JOIN makes vm ON v.make = vm.code and v.Make IN (6,8)
and v.group = '404'
```

Comment: This doesn't limit output makes to being IN the range; it returns all v.makes, inconsistent with their example. Granted the spec is poorly & ambiguously phrased.

Answer (score 1):

Join both tables using common field and let IN in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT    v.make, vm.description
FROM      vehicles v 
LEFT JOIN makes vm 
ON        vm.code = v.make
WHERE     v.group = 404 
AND       v.make IN (8,6);
```

Comment: OP cant use Group by just one column without having aggregate on other, Please Remove `group by`

Comment: @BHouse An aggregate is not needed with a group by. However any non-aggregate returned has to be functionally dependent on the group by column set. If the asker's group by was legal then there's one description per make & if it was needed then presumably it was instead of a select distinct.

Answer (score 1):

List `makes` first and join to `vehicles`. Additionally, nothing in the current JOIN related the two tables. The `JOIN`'s `ON` clause needs an expression to compare a column from the `vehicles` table with a column from the `makes` table.

```
SELECT v.make, vm.description
FROM makes vm 
LEFT JOIN vehicles v ON v.make = vm.code
WHERE v.group = 404
```

But this still won't produce your example results, because the example results and some columns in your query don't fit the test data. Therer's something important you haven't told us yet.

Comment: The asker's query is not what they want, but how do you justify that their output is not what they want? They (poorly) say they want v.makes IN a range. But you don't use the range at all--did you forget?

Answer (score 1):

The LEFT JOIN returns all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table. If you want to return all makes, even if there is no corresponding vehicle you're looking for RIGHT JOIN. If you want to include vehicles with no makes as well use OUTER JOIN.